# Determining the range of $\phi$ for the volume between 3D shapes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Problem:

Find the volume of the solid that lies within the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, above the xy plane, and outside the cone $z=4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

My attempt:

The triple integral of: ($p^2\sin{\phi}$) dp d$\phi$ d$\theta$

Range of p: $0$ <= p <= 3; as the volume lies above the xy plane.

Range of $\theta$: $0$ <= $\theta$ <= 2$\pi$; as we are dealing with spherical objects.

Range of $\phi$: $0$ <= $\phi$ <= $\arcsin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}}$; by calculating the intersection of the shapes.

Why is $\phi$ wrong? Apparently the range was supposed to be:

$\arcsin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}}$ <= $\phi$ <= $\pi/2$

Which to me doesn't make sense graphically. That bounds $\phi$ weirdly when I draw it out. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: In the second part you misunderstood $\phi$ taking it as the latitude being the colatitude or polar angle. This means that $\phi=0$ for $x=y=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$ for the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Your range of phi computed the area within the sphere and *inside* the cone. You were correct with the intersection, but the volume for the portion inside the sphere and outside the cone goes from the intersection down to the xy-plane.

Comment: This is what you found with your range: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TISphericalCoords_files/image002.gif

Comment: Thank you, that clears everything up!